# How to calculate how much the company saved after % increase and decrease in two departments

Tags: percentages, ratio

Company X has increased the hourly rate of the accounting department by 40% from the original rate of $60 (the total hours used 4450).

AND the company decreased the hourly rate of the logistics department by 20% from the original rate of $100 (total hours used 10100). How much did the company save?

the answer was -95,200 and according to the manual, it was saving (even though the answer has a negative sign).

The way I worked it out is as follows. 
(1.40*$60* 4450) - (0.80 *$100*10100) = -434200. 
The manual used this instead
40%*60*4450 - 20%*100*10100 = -95,200 which doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: If something of price 1.00 has a discount and pass to a new price of 0.80, how much is the saving? 0.2 or 0.8?

Comment: 20% saving. ???

Comment: Ok, 0.80 is the final price, 0.20 is the saving. Now, returning to your problem, how must money is saving each deparment (not which is its final cost)

Comment: the logistics department is saving 20 dollars from the hourly rate of 100 dollars per hour resulting in  80 dollars /hour.

Comment: However, accounting department increased its hourly wage from 60 dollars to 84 dollars (40 % increase)

Comment: Yesterday you buy one apple by 1.00$ and one orange by 2.00$. Today you buy an apple by 1.20$ and one orange by 1.60$.  How much money do you expend yesterday? How much today? How much is the saving from yesterday to today?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65206/discussion-between-emma-and-pasaba-por-aqui).

Comment: 4500 or 4450? What is the right number?

Comment: @alexjo it is 4550 , my mistake just corrected it in the original post

Comment: @emma See my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's an increase in the cost for the accounting department, and a decrease in the cost for the logistics department. If the decrease is larger in magnitude than the increase, then the company saved money.

The way you solved it includes the original amounts that the company was spending on each department, which is incorrect. You only should consider the *change* in the two amounts, which is what the solution gives you.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer. But the way I solved it includes the change in the price (e.g. 40% increase of $100 is 1.40*100 not 40%*100). Bear with me as my basics in percentages is very bad( hence the practice questions that I do).

Answer (score 0):

Without change of each rate we have that the total expense $S$ is the sum of the expense of the accounting department $S_a$ and the expense of the logistics department $S_l$
$$
S=S_a+S_l=60\times 4450+100\times 10100
$$
With change we have that $S_a$ changes of $\Delta S_a$ and $S_l$ changes of $\Delta S_l$
$$
\begin{align}
S'=S+\Delta S&=(S_a+\Delta S_a)+(S_l+\Delta S_l)\\
&=(S_a+S_l)+(\Delta S_a+\Delta S_l)\\
&=S+(\Delta S_a+\Delta S_l)\\
&=60\times (1+0.4)\times 4450+100\times (1-0.2)\times 10100\\
&=(\underbrace{60\times 4450}_{S_a}+\underbrace{60\times 0.4\times 4450}_{\Delta S_a})+(\underbrace{100\times 10100}_{S_l}+\underbrace{100\times (-0.2)\times 10100}_{\Delta S_l})\\
&=\underbrace{(60\times 4450+100\times 10100)}_{S=S_a+s_l}+\underbrace{(60\times 0.4\times 4450-100\times 0.2\times 10100)}_{\Delta S=\Delta S_a+\Delta S_l}
\end{align}
$$
and the saving is
$$
S'-S=\Delta S=\Delta S_a+\Delta S_l=60\times 0.4\times 4450-100\times 0.2\times 10100
$$
It is a saving because $\Delta S<0$ and $S' <S $ that is the final expense is less than the initial expense.